# creating a view showing nodes referenced from the currently selected node

Tags: views

I have a content type called shops and another called products. on creating a product content, one can type in the shops name, which is provided as an autocomplete node reference field. what i would like to achieve is to create a view showing products in a selected shop. how can i achieve this. I have tried to use reverse node reference module but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reverse Node References](https://drupal.org/project/reverse_node_reference) is indead a good solution as it should provide what your are asking for. [It's documentation](https://drupal.org/node/965910) describe how to use for that exact purpose: query children nodes referencing a parent node matching a filter.

Another solution is the [Node Referrer](https://drupal.org/project/nodereferrer) module which will create a auto-populated fields on the parent content type with references to all the nodes referencing it. You can then build a view using this field to create a relationship to the children nodes.